# Как на T-SQL определить условие для выборки данных из JSON?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Есть следующий JSON:

```
{ "data":[
   {"items":[
      ["name1", "value1"], 
      ["name2", "value2"], 
      ["value3"]
   ]}     
]}
```

Надо получить таблицу

```
name    values
name1   value1
name2   value2
null    value3
```

Использую следующий SQL:

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"data":[{"items":[
                                            ["name1","value1"],
                                            ["name2","value2"],
                                            ["value3"]]}]}'
select names, [values]  
from openjson(@json, '$.data') with (items nvarchar(max) '$.items' as json)
cross apply openjson(items) with (
   names nvarchar(100) '$[0]', 
   [values] nvarchar(100) '$[1]'
)
```

Получаю

```
name1   value1
name2   value2
value3  NULL
```

Как сделать так, чтобы value3 выводился в столбце values?
Т.е. как задать условие в cross apply?

Comment: Сейчас в JSON так и есть ["value3"], но фактически должно быть ["name3", "value3"]. Но "name3" отсутствует. Надо выводить вместо него NULL. Для этого надо как-то задать условие, но как это сделать - непонятно.

Comment: Имел ввиду другое. Вот есть ***value*** без _name_ может ли быть ***name*** без _value_, или таких данных не может быть? По-хорошему входные данные должны быть нормализованы в `[null, "value3"]`. Тогда запрос сработает.

Comment: Согласен. Есть правильные ["name1", "value1"] и такие ["value3"] - неправильные.  
Из-за ошибки на клиенте в базе данных оказалось много ненормализованных записей. Надо как-то исправить их с помощью sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в данных может отсутствовать только `"name"`-часть, а `"value"`-часть отсутствовать не может, то можете попробовать такой запрос

```
select
    names = iif([1] is NULL, NULL, [0]),
    [values] = iif([1] is NULL, [0], [1])
from
    openjson(@json, '$.data')
        with (items nvarchar(max) '$.items' as json)
    cross apply openjson(items)
        with ([0] nvarchar(100) '$[0]', [1] nvarchar(100) '$[1]')
```

По-хорошему входные данные должны быть нормализованы в `[null, "value3"]`. Тогда исходный запрос сработает.